# How to check value of a textbox that contain _age at the end?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This might be some odd question but it is the problem I am facing. I have textBox with Id like:

```
"pax_9495237e-5c9e-489f-8700-2f82e211fd51__Age"
"pax_9495237e-9h7e-489f-8700-2f82e211fd51__Age"
"pax_9495237e-9k2e-489f-8700-2f82e211fd51__Age"
```

Now I want to check if all Textboxes consist of `__Age` at the end, has numeric value or not. If not numeric(INT) i.e. characters(no .) not allowed then make an alert.
Please help me I don't know how to do it. I know I have a class option but I want to do by Id.

Comment: "pax_9495237e-5c9e-489f-8700-2f82e211fd51__Age" is it an id or class..??

Comment: So ... are those IDs? Regex? Your qeustion makes 0 sense

Comment: Has numeric value or not...??

Comment: Updated my answer to include your updated answer.

Comment: Updated again, using "textboxes" which I thought you ment textarea, but you questioned me so I'm guessing you mean input type=text. It doesn't matter what it is, just set your selector to that, use the filter, it works. See my [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/nPRkL/)

Comment: Just fyi, updated answer with pretty full explanation and extra information. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select you input, you can use this :

```
$('[id$="__Age"]')
```

Then to know if is a number

```
$('[id$="__Age"]').each(function(){
    if(isNaN(parseInt($(this).val()))){
        alert(this,id + ' is not a number');
    }
})
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/3B9Vp/

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='text'][id$='__Age']").each(function(){
        if(isNaN(parseInt($(this).val())))
            alert('Not an Integer');                
        else
            alert('It is an Integer');
    });
});
```

It will check all the textbox values that are ids ended with '__Age'

Comment: If i am not misstaken, .val() will return a string. You need to parse the string before `isNaN` else it will always return false.

Comment: Well. I am adding it dynamically, on button click. That is multiple age fields by clicking on add button. So I put on document.ready but it is not working.

Comment: Actually, i've tested my statement and it is actually false, you don't need to parse. But since the OP don't want decimal value, you need to parseInt

Comment: @Gautam3164 The condition of `if` or the alerts is wrong, change the second alert for the first and the first for the second... xD

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$("textarea").filter(function(i) { return $(this).prop("id").indexOf("__Age") !== -1; })
```

http://api.jquery.com/filter/
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/
[How to check whether a string contains a substring in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/method-like-string-contains-in-javascript)

## Working Example

```
//    an array of e.which|e.key codes that is every key code for every number and control (like shift, backspace, etc..)
var numsNcontrols = [48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,8,9,13,16,17,18,19,20,32,33,34,35,36,45,46,44,145,37,38,39,40];
//  first grab all inputs ending with "__Age", then asign "keydown" check for improper characters
$("input[type=text]").filter(function(i) { return $(this).prop("id").indexOf("__Age") !== -1; }).on("keydown", function(e) {
    if ($.inArray(e.which, numsNcontrols) == -1) return false;
})    //  now, using jQuery Chaining, we continue and asign keyup event to alert users they cannot enter anything but numbers
.on("keyup", function(e) {
    if ($.inArray(e.which, numsNcontrols) == -1) alert('Numbers only please!');
})

//  simple check value update to show how many textboxes end in "__Age"
$("#bil").val(
    $("input[type=text]").filter(function(i) { return $(this).prop("id").indexOf("__Age") !== -1; }).length
    + " textboxes have __Age at end of ID."
);

//  Shows in a textbox how many textboxes end in "__Age" && have a numeric value
$("#bad").val(
    $("input[type=text]").filter(function(i) { return $(this).prop("id").indexOf("__Age") !== -1 && !isNaN(parseInt($(this).val())); }).length
    + " textboxes have __Age at end of ID && numeric value."
);
```

***¡ALSO!*** Find a pretty full listing in one big object (full of smaller objects and arrays) of Key Codes [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/NePCm/)

Comment: @ProgrammerIT `input[type=text]`?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get all input ending with "__Age" you can use the jquery selector

```
jQuery( "[attribute$='value']" )
```

You can find more details [here](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

So, in your occasion you can call:

```
$('input[id$="__Age"]');
```

where all text boxes with an id ending in "__Age" will be returned.

In order to validate if the input is numeric you can check the value of each textbox and use [isNaN](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp) function provided in Javascript

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ppolyzos/dR9RS/1/) where there are 3 text boxes and  you call a function to check if their current value is numeric or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to show one alert when any of the inputs with `__Age` at the end has nonNumeric values then you can try something like this:

```
if($("input[type='text'][id$='__Age']").filter(function(){
    return !isNaN($(this).val()); //leave only those inputs with nonNumeric value
}).length) //count their lenght - if it's > 0 then show alert
    alert('There are inputs with "nonNumeric" values!');
```